# Como fazer um cálculo ao instanciar um objeto?

Tags: angular

Olá, eu gostaria de saber como faço para uma propriedade de um objeto receber um valor de uma contra entre outras propriedades, por exemplo

```
objeto = {
 valor1: 10,
 valor2: 2,
 valor3: valor1 * valor2 ????
}
```

estou tentando fazer isso em typescript, porém recebo um erro dizendo:

> 'cannot find name valor1'.

Agradeço

Comment: Não tem como fazer desse jeito porque o valor não está instaciado ainda.

Comment: ahhhh blz, vou tentar usar outra lógica então, obrigado